# Php: Laravel Undefined offset 1 al cargar un archivo a Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

Estoy trabajando un proyecto en PHP usando como framework laravel. Tengo que leer un archivo de texto separado por | y cargarlo a una base de datos Mysql.

Resulta que el archivo tiene 56 campos y 4700 registros. El codigo que estoy utilizando para realizar la carga es el siguiente:

```
       public function import (Request $request)
{
    $filename =  $request->file('select_file')->getRealPath();

    $data="LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '".$filename."' REPLACE INTO TABLE  act_table FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'"; 

    $pdo = DB::connection()->getPdo();
    $pdo->exec($data);
```

Esto funciona perfectamente con 3740 registros, pero si ingreso 3741 falla. 
He revisado la información y no hay error alguno en el archivo que estoy cargando. Incluso si parto el archivo en dos y los cargo por separado si me funciona, por lo cual estoy un poco desconcertado. Pareciera que se queda sin memoria o algo asi, pero el error me confunde un poco:

Undefined Offset 1.

Cabe mencionar que tambien he intentado realizar la carga utilizando un while pero me carga la misma cantidad de registros y genera el mismo error.

```
while(!feof($file)){
```

}

Comment: ¿Podrías poner el mensaje de error completo en la pregunta pulsando en [edit]? Gracias.

Comment: Gracias, ya logré solucionarlo. El Problema era bastante sencillo. My aplicación la estaba ejecutando con php artisan serve. Por lo que leí, tiene una limitación de no permitir cargas mayores a 2MB. Esto se soluciona cambiando la propiedad upload_max_filesize=128M. Yo lo solucioné cambiandome a ejecutar mi aplicacion en un servidor Apache con Xampp.

Answer (score 0):

Ya logré solucionarlo. El problema era que estaba ejecutando my aplicación con php artisan serve. Por lo que leī hay una propiedad que se llama upload_max_filesize que para artisan esta en 2mb y por ello no permite cargar archivos con tamaño mayor a ello.

En mi caso preferí migrarme a ejecutar mis pruebas en el servidor de Apache con Xampp. En el archivo php.ini está la propiedad upload_max_filesize en 128MB. Eso es suficiente para cargar mi archivo de solo 4 mb.